# How to handle the 404 error in libxmlparser in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

Can anyone suggest me how to handle the 404 error in my libxmlparser when there is no network connection available.

Thanks to all,
Monish.

Answer (score -1):

Display an error message & tell the user try again later?

What else could one do if there's no connection? Offer the user a crying towel? Call his help desk or ISP? Plug/unplug his ethernet cable?